# How to modify the classpath of an install4j launcher

Tags: install4j

My main installer (using InstallAnywhere ) is installing another installer (using install4j) in unattended mode. After the install4j installer is installed, the class path of the launcher has to be updated with the entries of some external jars installed as a part of the main installer (InstallAnywhere) outside the installation directory of the install4j installer.

How can I modify the class path of the launcher?

Comment: Do you need to update the classpath of an already installed launcher or are you taking about the classpath of the installer itself?

Comment: Actually Main installer(using Install Anywhere ) is installing another installer(using install4j) in unattended mode. So after the install4j installer is installed, the class path of the launcher has to be updated with the entries of some external jars installed as a part of main installer(InstallAnywhere) outside the install4j app installed location. Therefore I class path update action would be post installation.

Comment: OK, I edited the question with your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Launchers in install4j read a text file with a ".vmoptions" extension that contain VM parameters and optionally some special directives. For example, if the launcher is named "hello.exe", create a text file named "hello.vmoptions" next to it.

in the text file, add a line

```
-classpath/a [classpath]
```

where [classpath] is replaced with the additional class path for the launcher.

Comment: Thanks Ingo! I will do as you suggested.

Comment: I added the classpath entries  .vmoption file manually like below: